# Model usage within View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, model, asp.net-mvc-5

I think I'm not clear with the @model that can be part of the view
For example

```
@model MyModel
```

1. Is it the **input** argument that I can populate and call the view with?

   `return View("MyView", MyModel);`
2. Is it the **output** variable I can populate during the post of the view (for next control action)

   `[HttpPost]`

   `public ActionResult SomePostAction(MyModel myModel) //(and in post action)`
3. Is it **both** ??

Answer (score 0):

3, it's both!

It is called [model binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx). A feature of ASP.NET which makes it trivial to bind a mode to a view. Hence the name 'view model', which those models are usually called.

Assigning a model to your view gives you a so-called strongly typed view, which fully exposes the power over the Razor syntax.

The model binder is capable of binding the values of every input field back to the model when posting the `form`, as long as the `name` attribute of the form matches the name of the property on the view model. Html helpers such as `Html.EditorFor(m => m.SomeProperty)` makes this a trivial task.

As Mystere Man mentions, it's also possible to do this without an actual model in your view. For instance, this works:

Html (I omitted the form tag and submit button):

```
<input type="text" name="SomeString" />
```

with this method in your controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeAction(string someString)
{
   // ...
}
```

Comment: Kind of.  It's the Input.  Model binding happens regardless of what the @model statement is, although it certainly helps to format the data in the same format the model binder will expect.

Answer (score 0):

The `@model` declaration at the top of your view is related to the model object you passed to the `View()` method in your controller (option 1 in your question). The `@model` declaration is your way of telling the Razor view engine that the view is *strongly typed*. That means the C# compiler can double check any properties of your view accesses.

Suppose you had the following class

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Without a strongly typed view you might have something like this in your view

```
<div>
    Hello, @Model.Nmae
</div>
```

Notice that there's a typo in Name. ASP.Net has no idea what your model is so it has to use a dynamic object. You won't find that error until runtime. If you had delcared `@model MyModel` you would have an error at build time because MyModel doesn't have a Nmae property.

However, it's not uncommon to use the same model type as a parameter of the action. Imagine your page is an HTML form. In that case the model that your view is strongly typed to and the model that's passed to an MVC action could be the same.